# How does this circuit work? (TP4056, DW01)

Tags: arduino, capacitor, resistors, charger

Why are capacitors C13, C12, R20 used here?
And why resistor R18 and C5? (What function do they perform?)
I don't understand why they are installed there.

Datasheet:
[TP4056](https://static.chipdip.ru/lib/977/DOC002977110.pdf),
[DW01](https://www.ic-fortune.com/upload/Download/DW01-P_DataSheet_V10.pdf),
[FS8205A](https://www.ic-fortune.com/upload/Download/FS8205A-DS-12_EN.pdf).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capacitors C5, C13, and C12 are bypass or decoupling capacitors used to suppress high frequency noise and provide stable DC voltage at respective nodes. Resistors R18 and R20 seem to be some form of current limiting resistors to protect the pins they are attached to from excessive current which could damage the IC. Also note that this schematic is using 100k for R20 when datasheet for DW01 uses 100 ohm.

Comment: C5 value doesn't look like decoupling. But I'd suspect another mistake on the schematic.

Comment: @Brian Drummond, the location of C5 would indicate it should be a decoupling capacitor but it’s low capacitance value makes it confusing. I believe it is a mistake in schematic same as the 100k for R20. Even in TP4056 datasheet they use 10uF bypass capacitor. Though it could be that C5 was placed in wrong spot but that’s hard to know.

Comment: Agreed. To the questioner : better to be guided by the devices' datasheets and any white papers (app notes) you can find, rather than this schematic.